# Conditional redirects in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm not sure if what I want to achieve is even possible via .htaccess, I have trawled Google without any luck.

I have a pile of redirects to apply to a multi-store website which means that two domains will share the same .htaccess file. The problem that I have is that the redirects for each domain are conflicting with each other.

Is it possible set up the equivalent of a php 'if' statement within the .htaccess file without adding a condition before each redirect?

```
 <If domain = http://www.example-1.com>
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/en/1-2-drive-torque http://www.example-1.com/90-britool-expert-torque-wrenches
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/en/10-Britool http://www.example-1.com/24-britool-expert-spanners
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/en/11-Britool http://www.example-1.com/78-britool-expert-combination-spanners
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/en/12-Britool http://www.example-1.com/77-britool-expert-ratchet-spanners
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/en/13-Britool http://www.example-1.com/79-britool-expert-open-end-spanners
 etc...
 </If>

 <If domain = http://www.example-2.com>
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/en/1-2-drive-torque http://www.example-2.com/390-britool-expert-torque-wrenches
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/en/10-Britool http://www.example-2.com/624-britool-expert-spanners
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/en/11-Britool http://www.example-2.com/478-britool-expert-combination-spanners
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/en/12-Britool http://www.example-2.com/677-britool-expert-ratchet-spanners
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/en/13-Britool http://www.example-2.com/779-britool-expert-open-end-spanners
 etc...
 </If>
```

Any help or advice will be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use mod_rewrite for this instead and use the `%{HTTP_HOST}`. Unfortunately, there's no way to create "if" containers like you have in your example. You'll need to duplicate the condition each time:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example-1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^en/1-2-drive-torque /90-britool-expert-torque-wrenches [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example-1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^en/10-Britool /24-britool-expert-spanners [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example-1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^en/11-Britool /78-britool-expert-combination-spanners [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example-1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^en/12-Britool /77-britool-expert-ratchet-spanners [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example-1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^en/13-Britool /79-britool-expert-open-end-spanners [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example-2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^en/1-2-drive-torque /390-britool-expert-torque-wrenches [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example-2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^en/10-Britool /624-britool-expert-spanners [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example-2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^en/11-Britool /478-britool-expert-combination-spanners [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example-2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^en/12-Britool /677-britool-expert-ratchet-spanners [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example-2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^en/13-Britool /779-britool-expert-open-end-spanners [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, I thought that would be the case but wanted to check.